# Best Screw Option for Door Hinges without wood framing behind

Tags: doors, screws, door-frame, fastener

We have this metal door to our garage with a metal door frame. Unfortunately the 2x4s around the metal frame don't provide coverage to screw in the door hinges into the wood. This has been a problem since we got this mid century house, which the door always being loose.

What's the best solution here... Sheet metal screws? Adding something to the back?

You can see in the photos that our screw just come right through (I removed some of the already cracked drywall).

[image: Hinge View]

[image: View behind the door frame]

Comment: I see that the screw misses the wood, but is that because it's loose and not pointed at the wood? It seems to me that if you were to angle the screw to the left (from the 1st pic), it would angle into the wood behind the frame. Do the same with the other two screws (perhaps use longer screws to make up for the angle.

Comment: No, none of the screw holes have wood behind them if you line them up straight... Just nothing or sheetrock further down. It's as if the metal door frame was built in a way that the wood framing won't line up behind the screw holes.

Answer (score 2):

- Continue the disassembly of the damaged wall and infill the frame correctly.
- Drill out the holes (to an appropriate tap drill size) and tap for fine thread short flathead machine screws
- Continue the disassembly of the damaged wall and glue (using metal-filled epoxy, probably) nuts to the doorframe. Actually, one thick plate with all three holes drilled and tapped would work better (more glue area, can't break free and spin.)
- Continue the disassembly of the damaged wall and weld nuts to the doorframe. Don't set the house on fire.
- Cut out the section of doorframe under the hinge and weld in a thicker piece of steel. Don't set the house on fire. Drill and tap that for machine screws.
- Pump thickened epoxy into the void space and insert waxed screws while it cures.

Comment: Hmm, thank you. I don't think I'm gonna go with the last one because it sounds like it would make it much harder to detach the door in the future.

Comment: The door would come off easily (the point of waxing the screws is that you can unscrew them from the hardened epoxy, then mount the hinges with them,) the frame would fight more. Just providing options. If you are contemplating frame and door replacement, that would be one more approach, since fixing this one might be going well down the road to the work you'd need to do to just replace the frame.